# Android SDK "System Images, AVD's, etc) are they system dependent?

Tags: android, sdk

Right now I have Ubuntu, and Windows 7 Dual booted on my laptop. Both of which have Android SDK set up on them.

But when I had a very fast wifi network, I downloaded and installed all of the system images and everything else that was available for download, but only on my Ubuntu's Android SDK.

So since it was like 1.5GB of downloads, I am curious if they are dependent on the Linux system, and wouldn't work on Windows?

I am just curious if, instead of re-downloading all of that again, would I be able to transfer all the downloaded files from the SDK and transfer them onto my Windows Android SDK? Or would there be a compatibility issue, as if they will only work on the Linux System?

Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android SDK is not system independent.

The configuration files of your AVD are not system independent ( mainly because of the filesystem changes ).

The images of your AVD are system independent.

Comment: so I am not sure I understand you correctly. Think of it this way, you know when you set up Android SDK, in the SDK Manager, you have to download all the system images, the google usb driver, network drivers, manuals, etc. You can choose from the first android version all the way up to Jellybean now.  So which of those files that were downloaded from the SDK manager could I not transfer to my windows computer?

Comment: @insomnia so you are talking about _the platform_ itself, in this case after downloading it you can find all you have downloaded under `<Android SDK root>/platforms` and this files are system independent.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. That is exactly what I am referring to. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you go to the place where all the platform sdks are downloaded, that is http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml, you can browse through all system images, avd's, platforms, platform-tools, tools, etc.

So if you go to the sdk-archive xml element, of the things that you want to download, then you can check out the dependencies of the download in terms of architecture and operating system, so anything that has arch="any" and os="any" is effectively platform independent, and that counts for system images, samples, platforms, etc.

Also, if you are curious about where the extra stuff comes from, you can check out http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, and follow the link list, as usual an relative path in both repository-7.xml and addons_list-2.xml means that you should append http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/ to the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that you will be able to use the `Ubuntu's Android SDK` updates in `Windows 's Android SDK`.
As Android provides different `SDKS` for different platforms,you will have to redo all that you have done for `Ubuntu's Android SDK`.

Comment: I just want to make sure we are all on the same page.. These are not "updates". These are the "Android System Images" that run in a QEMU emulator. I dont see why they would be dependent. Im not saying can I just transfer my whole Android SDK and AVD over to windows. I mean the Android Emulation System Images. not the files that create SDK on a windows environment.